# React stale state with useEffect loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Given the following component:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

const Test = () => {
    const [thing, setThing] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    useEffect(() => {
        gameLoop();
    }, []);

    const gameLoop = () => {
        const p = {...thing};
        p.x++;
        setThing(p);
        setTimeout(gameLoop, 1000);
    }

    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Test;
```

Every second a new line is printed into the console. The expected output should of course be:

```
{ x: 1, y: 0 }
{ x: 2, y: 0 }
{ x: 3, y: 0 }
```

...etc

What is instead printed is:

```
{ x: 0, y: 0 }
{ x: 0, y: 0 }
{ x: 0, y: 0 }
```

I've come to the conclusion as this is because of a stale state. Some solutions I've found and tried are:

1. The dependency array

Adding thing to the dependency array causes it to be called ridiculously fast. Adding thing.x to the array also does the same.

2. Changing the setState call

One post I found mentioned changing the setState to look like so:

```
setState(thing => {
    return {
        ...thing.
        x: thing.x+1,
        y: thing.y
 });
```

Which changed nothing.

I have found a lot of posts about clocks/stopwatches and how to fix this issue with primitive value states but not objects.

What is my best course of action to fix the behavior while maintaining that it only runs once a second?

EDIT: The comments seem to be stating I try something like this:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

const Test = () => {
    const [thing, setThing] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(gameLoop, 1000);
     }, []);
     
     const gameLoop = () => {
        console.log(thing)
        const p = {...thing};
        p.x++;
        setThing(prevP => ({...prevP, x: prevP.x+1}));
     }

    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Test;
```

This still prints out incorrectly:

```
{ x: 0, y: 0 }
{ x: 0, y: 0 }
{ x: 0, y: 0 }
```

Comment: What about putting the game loop function inside the use effect?

Comment: You can simply pass a callback to `setThing` –  `function gameLoop() {setThing(prevP => ({...prevP, x: prevP.x+1})); setTimeout(gameLoop, 1000);}` setState will provide the up to date state value as an argument for the callback.

Comment: why don't you use setInterval instead?

Comment: @Max setInterval might not have the updated state either?

Comment: I mean you could use setInterval in the useEffect with the setState(thing => ...) inside. (I can try to write a solution if you want...)

Comment: I added an edit incorporating setInterval since it probably works better and the setThing(thing => syntax instead which still doesn't work. Someone let me know if I've done something incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use this solution:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setThing((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        x: prev.x + 1,
      }));
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
```

I suggest to control setInterval with the clearInterval when component is destroied; like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setThing((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        x: prev.x + 1,
      }));
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: This does indeed increment the x value correctly yes. Looking good.

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as the accepted answer.